# Validacion de XML medinte esquema XSD

Tags: python-3.x

Necesito validar un archivo XML mediante un esquema XSD y si el XML no es valido en su totalidad se guarden en un nuevo XML los tags que si sean validos.

```
xsd_doc = xmlschema.XMLSchema('protocolo/schema-definition.xsd')
xml_doc = XET.parse('protocolo/buffer.xml')
new_root = XET.Element("root")

for element in xml_doc.iter():
    if xsd_doc.is_valid(element):
        new_root.append(element)

new_xml = XET.tostring(new_root)
with open('protocolo/valid.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(new_xml)
```

Este es el codigo que estoy probando y me funciona solo si el XML es valido en su totalidad.

Comment: Realmente mi objetivo es la validación de un XML muy extenso lo cual se hace muy tedioso validar manualmente y el esquema XSD fue la mejor solución que encontré. Cualquier otra sugerencia será aceptada igualmente